# Cannot check the size of virtual machines in one region

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-availability-set

I am trying to check the availability size of virtual machines in one region.

The command: Get-AzVMSize -ResourceGroupName RG3 -AvailabilitySetName availabilitysets

However, it appears this error :-

> Get-AzVMSize is not recognized as an internal and external command.

Kindly please help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: I have created 2 virtual machines in an availability sets. However, I need to verify them in a virtual machine. The error is shown above. tq

Comment: Same here@jennie, We can get the vm sizes by passing the VM name(VM1 or VM2) using the below command as shown in answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tried to Getvmsize using below steps:

***Make sure to Connected with Azure using [*`Connect-AzAccount`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-7.4.0)***.

Then run the following command to list the vm sizes using availability sets name

```
Get-AzVMSize -ResourceGroupName "myrgname" -AvailabilitySetName "myavsetname"
```

&

`Get-AzVMSize -ResourceGroupName "myrgname" -VMName "myvmname"`

***OUTPUT SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]
[image]

---

[image]

For more information please refer this [***`MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION|Get-AzVMSize`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvmsize?view=azps-7.4.0)